# Is there a similar function to substr_count?

Tags: php

I use `substr_count` function to count how many times a word appears in a string. For example, given the sentence,

> saya akan menyalakan mobil di depan garasi

I want to count the words *akan* and *menyalakan* in this sentence.

I have used the function `substr_count` but the result is strange.

The result I am seeing is

```
"akan" = 2 word
"menyalakan" = 1 word
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have a look at the Perl Regular Expressions, `preg_match()` and use `"/\\w/"` for word matching or use `preg_split()` for splitting a sentence into words. The \w pattern "knows" about word boundaries.

Comment: "akan" is also a part of word "menyalakan" - this is why you get 2 as a result of `substr_count`. If you really want to use `substr_count` use spaces before and after each word ;)

Comment: no, the case like if i use notepad++, when I search a word use find, it will count many word I search at these document.

Comment: it'll complicated if i use spaces before and after each word, any function can I use for this case ? if substr_count not work, any other function seems like it who can count "menyalakan" and "akan" as different word ?

Comment: Please try to create a simple, self-contained example. Hardcode the source string, rather than pulling it from a database. Write a simple single-file PHP script which demonstrates the problem you are seeing. And then **post that code here**. How can we help you fix your code if you don't show us your code?

Comment: to : TRIG, Im so sorry, I'll post my code here. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try str_word_count()

```
 function countWord($str,$key) { 
   return array_count_values(str_word_count($str, 1))[$key];
 } 
 $str = "saya akan menyalakan mobil di depan garasi";

 echo countWords( $str , 'akan' );          // Output 1
 echo countWords( $str , 'menyalakan' );    // Output 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just log in again, thank's Mr. Samir it's seems like I want, I just change it to array like my database, thank's a lot Mr. Samir

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get information about words used in a string, you can use [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) and after that you can use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for count  for counting similar words.

If you want to search all case insensitive words process the array using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)($array, 'strtolower');

Example:

```
$all_words = str_word_count($str, 1);
$all_words = array_map($all_words, 'strtolower'); // optional
$count = array_count_values($all_words);

echo $count["akan"]; // 2;
echo $count["menyalakan"]; // 3;
```

Comment: and what you expect your `echo()`s to display?